# How to find the perimeter of a shaded shape when you know only one angle and one side

Tags: trigonometry, circles

[image: shaded area]

The diagram above ^^^

I am stumped as how to find the shaded area as I can only infer one angle and one side from the diagram.

Help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is the curve $CD$ part of a circle with radius $OC$?

Comment: I presume so yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $OB=BC$ the triangle OBC is isosceles.

If you draw a perpendicular from $B$ to $OC$ you know (due to isosceles) that the intersection point $M$ is in the middle of $OC$

In the new triangle $OBM$ you know a length $OM=9/2=4.5cm$ and two angles: $OBM=80/2=40$ and $BMO=90$. Then you can find $OB$ and angle $BOC$.

The rest is easy. If you want the area of shaded then find the area of a circular sector and substract the area of the triangle. For the perimeter, now you have $BOC$ and distance $BC=OB$.

Comment: Ah that's helpful. Many thanks.